# RSS affiliate iTunes php parser

Tags: php, rss, itunes

I tried to create a PHP script in order to extract all the data but this is not working. I tried to get the `im:price` and other attributes but I don't know how to get them.

Can anyone help me correct my script?

```
 <?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('https://itunes.apple.com/fr/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=25/xml');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $node) {
    $item = array (
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'price' => $node->getElementsByTagName('im')->item(0)->getAttribute('price')
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,

    );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 5;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p> Price is '.$price.'</p>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to parse all of the `im` nodes you have to use namespaces like so.

```
$namespaces = $entry->getDocNamespaces(true);
$items = $entry->children($namespaces['im']);
```

Here is a sample to get you started:

```
<?php 

$rss = "https://itunes.apple.com/fr/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=25/xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($rss);

  foreach ($xml->entry as $entry){

$namespaces = $entry->getDocNamespaces(true);

$items = $entry->children($namespaces['im']);

$name = $items->name;
$summary = $entry->summary;
$price = $items->price;
$image = $items->image[1];
$rights = $entry->rights;
```

For all of the `im` nodes use `$items->foo;`. For all of the nodes without the `im` namespace use `$entry->bar;`